# How to cache a concurrent hashmap at the operator level in Flink streaming?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Probably similar to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289319/how-to-cache-the-local-variable-at-process-level-in-flink-streaming), but my goal is to share a concurrent hashmap across all parallelisms in a single flat map operator.

I have a hashmap that contains a <Integer, Integer> mapping, and I want this map to be shared among all the task slots that run my flatmap function.

The reason that I want it shared is because my flatmap is keyed via *2* values in a Tuple2, the first value being the key I care about and the second value being a secondary key as I want each event with the two key combo to end up in one worker and aggregated. Therefore, the first key may end up in multiple worker threads, so I want a way to share a gigantic hashmap across all of them like a cache of some sort.

Is this possible with Flink? Is it even a good idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the whole tuple as a key as you want each event with the two key combo to end up in on task?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but you might achieve it with a BroadcastState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you add the second tuple field to the key, you're not guaranteed that each key `<A, x>` will get sent to a slot that's in the same TaskManager instance. So unless you're running with a single TM, this won't work.